# What´s the easiest way to generate specific sequence in python2?

Tags: python

What would be the easiet/quickiest way to generate sequence 0,1,3,4,6,7,... as a list in python2?

Comment: Rather than worrying about the fastest way, have you made any progress in any way to do this yourself?

Comment: so, skip every third number?

Comment: How do you know where the list is to stop?

Comment: Well, it's going to be a list comp - what have you tried?

Comment: @SiHa why is it going to be a list-comp?

Comment: OK, should have said "probably". It's generally the simplest way to generate a simple list. I accept, however, that to the newcomer they can be more confusing than a simple for loop.

Comment: Because when generating a list - a list comprehension is a natural option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the pattern continues skipping every third number, this will work (in this example sequence goes up to 100, but you can edit):

```
upper_limit = 100
my_list = [i for i in range(upper_limit) if (i+1) % 3]
```

Giving:

```
[0,
 1,
 3,
 4,
 6,
 7,
 9,
 10,
 12,
...
...
 93,
 94,
 96,
 97,
 99]
```

This works because the numbers being skipped are always 1 less than integers which are evenly divisible by 3, so `%` can be used to test whether a number should be included. See documentation for [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) and [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and you should be able to work out how to generate lists for other similar patterns.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you're going to have to specify how far to go, and a list comprehension is the natural choice for generating a list with code.  The only hard bit is working out what values are to be left out of the list:

```
max = 20
required_sequence = [value for value in range(max) if (value + 1) % 3 != 0]
```